# How to search for a specific character at the end of user input?

Tags: python, python-2.7

As a new python user, I am trying to create something along the lines of a Magic 8 Ball. I want to make it search for  a ? at the end of the statement in the user input to determine if it is a question or not and make it respond accordingly. My current code is

```
import random
x = 1
while (x == 1):
    list_1 = ['Yes', 'No', 'Never', 'Possibly', 'Try again']
    response = raw_input('What is your question? (Press enter to exit) ')
    if (response == ''):
        break
    else:
        print random.choice(list_1)
```

Comment: `response.rstrip()[-1] == "?"`

Comment: `if response.endswith("?")`

Comment: @iBug: The string `raw_input()` returns won't end with a newline, so that's not correct.

Comment: @martineau It doesn't matter, `rstrip()` doesn't strip question marks. You may say "it's unnecessary", but you can't say "it's wrong".

Comment: @martineau The strip should just return the unmodified string then, no? In which case it's a waste...but still works

Comment: @iBug: OK it would work, but in that case wouldn't be simpler and faster to just use `response[-1] == "?"` — which would be faster than kindall's suggestion, but arguably less readable.

Comment: @martineau Yep, you're right that it's simpler and faster. I mainly write Python 3 code so all my style and most of my knowledge are based on P3, not P2.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the last sighn is "?" by  indexing:

```
if response[-1] == '?':
    #whatever you want
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if '?' in response:
    #do whatever
```

If you specifically want to check the last character (which I don't personally think is necessary) you can use

```
if response[-1] == '?':
    #do whatever
```

As kindall mentioned in the comments, you can also do

```
if response.endswith('?'):
    #do whatever
```